# How to obtain and interact with QWidgets from QProcess

Tags: c++, qt

I have `Application A` which is a third party Windows application (with GUI) that uses the Qt library.

I want to write `Application B` which will be responsible for starting `Application A`.  I want `Application B` to also find buttons on `Application B` (`QWidgets`) and send them mouse inputs (click, double click etc).

I can run `Application A` through using the `start` function on a `QProcess`.

How do I do the following from my instance of the `QProcess`:

1. Get the top level window(s) for the process
2. Get a widget by name or (other identifiable attribute)
3. Get the widgets caption, colour and coordinates (and maybe some other data)
4. Send mouse move and click events to specific coordinates
5. Give a widget keyboard focus
6. Send keyboard key presses

Note - I know how to do this with the Windows API, but asking for a way via Qt.  The specific `Application A` in question does not use the native windowing system, therefore window handles will not show up in Spy++ or Windows API functions.

**Update 1 - Cannot seem to get any meaningful objects through the process's children**

My attempt at getting child widgets for the process:

```
QProcess* process = new QProcess();
QString program = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\foo\\bar.exe\"";
process->start(program);
auto widgets = process->findChildren<QWidget*>("", Qt::FindChildrenRecursively);
auto i = widgets.count();
// i = 0
```

If I find children of type `<QObject*>` I get 4 results.  I used `metaObject()->className()` to see that I have two pairs of QWindowsPipeReader and QWinOverlappedIoNotifier objects.

**Update 2 - Cannot create/inject window from another process**

I noticed that when I run the QProcess I can use Windows API functions to get the top level window (top level only).  I read in the Qt documentation that you can create a QWindow from the handle of a window in another process using [QWindow::fromWinId](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#fromWinId).

Using this function will throw an `0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.` error.  I am not passing in a null handle.  I am using reinterpret_cast to get the `HWND` to a `WId` type.  It creates a QWindow only when I create a QApplication beforehand.

The new QWindow will have no children (using `window->findChildren<QObject*>("", Qt::FindChildrenRecursively);`  I assume that the creation of the QWindow does not bring across associated child widgets.

**Update 3 - I am currently reading into whether inter-process communication can be used**

I have come across various threads, questions and code snippets regarding [ICP in Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ipc.html).  I don't see anything so far that specifically shows that ICP is possible when one of the processes is third party.

I have seen that the Squish Gui test tool lets you interrogate QWidget properties.

Comment: Have a look at Qt Accessiblity: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt4-accessibility.html

Comment: Your attempt will never work. Qt doesn't include functionality to access foreign process's objects.

Comment: "I am currently reading into whether inter-process communication can be used" Either it's not true that Application A is a third party application, or you're wasting time. If App A is third party and you have no access to the source code, then your only way to gain access to it is to inject your own code. Since you'll need access to A's Qt, the easiest way to inject is via a substituted, binary-compatible Qt.

Comment: Note that everything you're trying to do (points 1 ~ 6) is doable without having any access to A's internals. You can easily discern widgets and useful key points within them by using off-the-shelf image recognition libraries. WINAPI lets you easily inject messages into a separate process.

Comment: Image comparison is our plan B.  I thought that under the hood Qt would allow you to at least hook into a top level window/object that I can track all the way down (much like Windows API and XWindows tools in Linux).

Comment: I can see problems with point 6, as I need to set focus to a window (e.g. text box window) using a window handle... image comparison method won't give me that option.

Comment: @rasteve Just send a mouse click to set focus. The text box isn't a window, it's a non-native control that doesn't have a HWND. There's little difference here between Qt Widgets, Qt Quick and WPF: they all use non-native controls. A top window in Qt Quick or WPF is just a Direct3D surface.

Comment: @rasteve The WINAPI or X11 native controls are not used in any of the modern applications, so you might as well forget about them. They are a historical artifact at this point. No modern code that runs on Windows or X11 uses any of that junk. Qt's job isn't to make it easier for people like you to reverse engineer someone else's applications. You shouldn't "think" what Qt does under the hood, just read the source and you won't have to guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will never work the way you intend it to.

If you really wish to take direct control over the other application, you must inject your code into that application. Let's assume that the application uses a dynamically linked Qt. Then:

1. Build a binary-compatible version of Qt, using the same compiler that was used to build the application you intend to tweak.
2. Replace the application's Qt with yours. Everything should still work fine, given that yours should be binary compatible. If not, the binary compatibility isn't there, and you must tweak things until they work.
3. Edit your Qt to add a hook to initialize your code at the end of `QApplication` constructor. This makes the Qt module that provides `QApplication` dependent on your code.
4. Put your code into a dll that the widgets (for Qt 5) or gui (for Qt 4) module is now dependent on.
5. Again replace the app's Qt with yours, with hooks that start your code.

Your code will of course need to be asynchronous, and will be monitoring the application's progress by inspecting the `qApp->activeWindow()`, `qApp->allWidgets()`, etc.

That's pretty much the only way to do it. You can of course inject your code in any other way you desire, but you will need to work with a binary-compatible version of Qt just to compile your code. Note that binary compatibility encompasses more than merely using the same compiler version and Qt version. Many of the `configure` switches must be the same, too.

Comment: Are you sure this is the only way?  Is this how tools like Squish work?

Comment: Squish injects its own code into the target application, and proceeds to use various heuristics to hook itself into the Qt that runs there. If you're serious about controlling App A without replacing its Qt, you'll be much better off licensing the qt hook and perhaps squishrunner code from froglogic. It will cost you orders of magnitude less than developing it from scratch. That's why you should replace App A's Qt. My bet is that it should be an afternoon job if you have MSDN subscription and access to relevant compiler versions (you should, your time is more valuable!)